# PHPExcel - DOMPdf Connection Reset

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

I'm using PHPExcel library to generate a report for my website. I'm using it with DOMPdf to export the reports to PDF. This works fine for small reports, but when I have a lot of data to export it shows "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".
Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Any help will be very appreciated.

This is the code that I'm using to generate pdf:

```
public function export_pdf($objPHPExcel,$nameFile){

    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
    $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf';
    $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Vendor/' . $rendererLibrary;
    PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath);

    $chartRendererName =   PHPExcel_Settings::CHART_RENDERER_LIBCHART;
    $chartRendererLibrary = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Vendor/libchart/classes';
    PHPExcel_Settings::setChartRenderer($chartRendererName, $chartRendererLibrary);

    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheetIndex();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(false);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'PDF');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($worksheet);
    $date = new DateTime();
    $objWriter->save('outputfiles/'.$nameFile.$date->getTimestamp().'.pdf');
    $url = Router::url('/outputfiles/', true).$nameFile.$date->getTimestamp().'.pdf';
    return $url;
}
```

This is what I'm getting in php_error.log:

```
[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP   6. ReportsController->getTodosforReport() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php:490

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP   7. ReportsController->reservesWithTraces() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Controller\ReportsController.php:966

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP   8. ReportsController->export_pdf() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Controller\ReportsController.php:1099

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP   9. PHPExcel_Writer_PDF->save() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Controller\ReportsController.php:947

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP  10. PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_DomPDF->save() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Vendor\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF.php:87

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP  11. spl_autoload_call() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Vendor\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF.php:94

[16-May-2016 15:42:30 America/New_York] PHP  12. DOMPDF_autoload() C:\xampp\htdocs\reinier\app\Vendor\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF.php:0
```

**UPDATE**:
I added this two lines to the function below and nothing changes

```
 ini_set("memory_limit", '1024M');
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Any other suggestion?

**UPDATE**:

This is what I get in apache error.log file

```
[Tue May 17 17:23:33.737245 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00428: Parent: child process 15620 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Tue May 17 17:23:34.453984 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:23:34.545773 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 17 17:23:34.545773 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Tue May 17 17:23:34.545773 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp_183\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp_183/apache'
[Tue May 17 17:23:34.548702 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9356
[Tue May 17 17:23:35.122875 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 9356:tid 536] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:23:35.373832 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 9356:tid 536] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:23:35.417773 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9356:tid 536] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue May 17 17:25:11.545808 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00428: Parent: child process 9356 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.264499 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.307465 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.308442 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.308442 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp_183\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp_183/apache'
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.310395 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14132:tid 580] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 11884
[Tue May 17 17:25:12.858201 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 11884:tid 564] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:25:13.098416 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 11884:tid 564] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue May 17 17:25:13.143335 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11884:tid 564] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Wow! Somebody has added a LibChart renderer for charts?!? Pity they haven't contributed it to the PHPExcel library.

Comment: @Mark Baker, I only did it for bar charts, that's the reason why I didn't consider to contribute to PHPExcel library. Do you have any idea why this error is happening?

Comment: The most likely causes are timeout or memory; is anything being written to the logs?

Comment: @Mark Baker, I have specified  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); to avoid timeout in the function that calls this function.

Comment: Looks like the error could be in the DOMPDF Autoloader, as the last entry in the log; but difficult to say much beyond that

Comment: @Mark Baker, the error only happens when there is too many data to export, also the pdf file is created twice. This doesn't happen with little data.

Comment: Then an out of memory error is most likely; though why it should create the PDF twice, I have no idea

Comment: @Mark Baker, I also specified in the other function   ini_set("memory_limit", '4096M'); and the same is happening

Comment: Can your PHP access 4GB of memory? I'm aware of two typical cause for connection reset: out or memory, or timeout

Comment: @Mark Baker, I'm running a 32 bit version of XAMPP on a 64 bit version of Windows. So if I'm not mistaken it can only theoretically access a little bit under 4GB. Anyway I'm not seeing any change.

Comment: A connection reset rather than a 500 has, in my experience, been the result of a crash of the web server (typically apache). If this is the case you won't see any indication in the PHP log, check the apache log.

Comment: @BrianS, I updated the question with the apache error.log file

Comment: That does look to be an apache thread crash. The cause [is indeterminte](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+Parent%3A+child+process+exited+with+status+3221225725+--+Restarting), you would need a crash dump to analyze. But based on this conversation I'd agree with @MarkBaker that it's probably a memory over-run, but in apache instead of PHP. Maybe [increase the apache thread stack size](http://www.codexpedia.com/apache-server/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225725-restarting-on-xamp-apache/) (via my above google search)?

Comment: @BrianS, thanks for your comment, that solved my issue, please post it as answer so I can set it as the correct answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment back-and-forth:

A connection reset rather than a 500 has, in my experience, been the result of a crash of the web server (typically apache). If this is the case you won't see any indication in the PHP log but you would see a notice in the apache log.

The error you are seeing

> Parent: child process 15620 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.

does look to be an apache thread crash. The crash indicated by this log entry is [indeterminte](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+Parent%3A+child+process+exited+with+status+3221225725+--+Restarting), you would need a crash dump to analyze. But based on the comments I'd agree with Mark that it's probably a memory over-run, but in apache instead of PHP.

Maybe [increase the apache thread stack size](http://www.codexpedia.com/apache-server/parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225725-restarting-on-xamp-apache/) (via my above google search)?